# While calling CosmosClient(url,key,proxy_config = d) in python i am getting error?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, cosmosclient

While using client to configure and execute requests to the Azure Cosmos DB service

```
`
d=ProxyConfiguration()
d.Host='string'
d.Port=int
client = CosmosClient(url,key,proxy_config = d) `
```

I am getting error

```
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError:<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020EC3BCCD60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

What is the right way to pass the  values to proxy_config parameter ?

[CosmoClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmos/azure.cosmos.cosmosclient?view=azure-python)

Comment: You need to specificy a `ProxyConfiguration`, not a string. And `ProxyConfiguration()` takes a `Host` (string) and `Port` (int) parameter.

Comment: i made few changes in my code, have a look into it.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?